# Spring passing parameter values via annotations for current user

Tags: java, spring, annotations, parameter-passing

I'm developing some social system, and I want make some annotation which automatically inject loggedUser to method parameter.

I've tried to use a AOP but official documentation says:

> Return types are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types. Methods can have default values.

```
public void getLoggedUserDetails( @CurrentUser User user){
//some logic
}
```

It it possible to do that with Aspects and annotaion or I should look for another solution?

Comment: This is really not a suitable candidate for AOP. What's wrong with  just `getLoggedUserDetails() { User user = someService.getCurrentUser(); ... } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a `@AuthenticationPrincipal` and it works for controller method parameters. see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html)

```
@Controller
class UserController {


    @GetMapping("/self")
    public ResponseEntity<User> demo(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

You can also create a custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {}
```

see details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal)